# Laravel resource syntax

Tags: laravel, api, routes

If Laravel route is like this,

```
$api->resource('invoices.payments', 'Incomes\InvoicePayments');
```

What is the url to call for API? I'm confused with that "." between **invoices** and **payments**.

I tried `.../invoices.payments`, `.../invoicespayments` and `.../invoices_payments` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that this would generate a nested resource like:

```
/invoices/{invoices}/payments
/invoices/{invoices}/payments/{payments}
```

etc.

You can run `php artisan route:list` to see the available routes you have.